# Is there a 'best' Google charts API for PHP?

Tags: php, google-visualization

Is there a "best" one? Does it offer as much flexibility as the Google API?

I am wary of using such wrapper, as I would need to take the time to evaluate each individually, so I am asking here if anyone has already done this.

Are there any benefits in a wrapper? The Google API seems clear enough.

And what guarantee is there that a wrapper will be updated as Google updates its API.

I would need something that can be used commercially. Should I even bother to look, or just stick with Goggle's API?

I woudl prefer to use POST, for larger datasets (and privacy).

---

Btw, please don't just google & post some links - I can do that myself. I'd like to hear from people who have actually used a wrapper. Thanks.

---

[This](http://www.splitbrain.org/blog/2008-04/16-google_chart_api_via_php) makes an interesting read; it's the sort of thing I want to hear more of.

"What I was especially missing was some logic that automagically prepares the data for the chart. Eg. I'd expect the library to create sensible scaled axis labels on its own."

There is a good list of wrappers [here](http://groups.google.com/group/google-chart-api/web/useful-links-to-api-libraries)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is never a "best". Only a better for your case.

Various chart API exist, see http://free-wiz.blogspot.com/2008/07/best-free-chart-apis.html

Comment: +1 thanks. I already saw that one when googling. It just mentions one Ruby and one JS api for google charts, but no PHP. I want a PHP wrapper, or none at all. Thanks for trying to help, though.

Comment: I used [pChart](http://pchart.sourceforge.net/) which has a PHP API. However I usually prefer to make my own wrapper and use other charting libraries.

Comment: +1 for Pchart, but I think I have settled on Google charts (GraPHPite looked good too)

Comment: -1  The question is about google charts and PHP specifically. gchartphp is another option. Interested how that might compare with http://code.google.com/p/googchart/, but the latter seems to have much less activity.

Answer (score 3):

gchartphp look nice and recently updated, http://code.google.com/p/gchartphp/